# How to detect uninstallation of an Android app and remove related user's data from the server?

Tags: php, android, mysql, sqlite, uninstallation

Basically, I want to remove all the web postings that a user has made via my Android application in the event the user uninstalls my app. Is that even possible?

Comment: "Is that even possible?" -- in a word, no.

Comment: I put an answer below that I believe to be correct. I will only comment on a rather crappy work-around. You can have your app ping the server every day to tell it that it is still installed.

Comment: @kainaw that cannot be a sure way right.. What if there is not internet connection for a whole week. That does not mean that the app is uninstalled

Comment: @Msk I didn't say it was a "sure" way. I said it was a "crappy" way.

Comment: Why would you even want to? Whats the use case? What if someone gets a new phone? Are you _trying_ to hack off your users?

Answer (score 4):

No you cannot do that, as the app cannot understand when the application is being uninstalled.
If the data to be deleted from the server is such that the user will want it removed, you could make a button in the code, for the user to press, which will invoke process of deleted data on the server. Else just in un-installation, you will not be able to do it

Answer (score 2):

I suggest since your talking about server side code write in some logic that checks the last update date/time on the records and then email the user.

Something to the effect that if they do not click on a link within X days their account will be deleted/purged. If they click the link then just update a single records last update date/time.

Answer (score 1):

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED

The package does NOT receive the intent that it is being removed.